# How to add timezone offset to JSON.NET serialization?

Tags: c#, json.net

My DateTimePicker is bound to property:

```
    picker.DataBindings.Add("Value", this, "EventDate");
    ...
    private DateTime eventDate;
    public DateTime EventDate
    {
        get
        {
            var offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(eventDate);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventDate, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine("get: {0} --- {1}", json, offset);
            return eventDate;
        }
        set
        {
            var offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(value);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine("set: {0} --- {1}", json, offset);
            eventDate = value;
        }
    }
```

Whenever data binding is to set the property, I've got the following result:

```
set: "2015-08-03T16:06:59" --- 04:00:00
get: "2015-08-03T16:06:59" --- 04:00:00
```

The code in get/set only for debug purposes. The whole class is serialized along with EventDate property.

How can I modify DateTime variable and/or json serializer in order to include timezone offset such as:

```
"2014-08-03T16:06:59.8708232+04:00"
```

Strange thing is if I create brand new DateTime object and assign to DateTime.Now without binding, JSON.NET will append timezone offset to it. Can't figure out what is the difference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried type [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb341783(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DateTime`? This is the type with timezone information.

```
var example = new
{
    Now = DateTimeOffset.Now,
    UtcNow = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    Sometime = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 10, 11, 1, 4, 9, new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0)),
    FromDateTime = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1)),
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(example, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Gives me:

```
{
  "Now": "2014-08-03T22:08:47.8127753+08:00",
  "UtcNow": "2014-08-03T14:08:47.8137754+00:00",
  "Sometime": "2014-10-11T01:04:09+08:00",
  "FromDateTime": "2010-01-01T00:00:00+08:00"
}
```

**EDIT - Alternative way**

You noticed that `DateTime.Now` has timezone offset in JSON while manually created `DateTime` does not. This is because `DateTime.Now` has `Kind` equal to `DateTimeKind.Local` while the other has `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, and JSON.NET just handles them differently.

So the alternative way is:

```
var product2 = new
{
    Now = DateTime.Now,
    Sometime = new DateTime(2014, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0),
    SometimeLocal = new DateTime(2014, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local),
    SometimeUtc = new DateTime(2014, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
};

string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product2, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(json2);
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  "Now": "2014-08-03T23:39:45.3319275+08:00",
  "Sometime": "2014-10-11T00:00:00",
  "SometimeLocal": "2014-10-11T00:00:00+08:00",
  "SometimeUtc": "2014-10-11T00:00:00Z"
}
```

**EDIT2 - For data binding**

OK you use data binding. Then you can update your setter to convert automatically:

```
picker.DataBindings.Add("Value", this, "EventDate");
...
private DateTimeOffset eventDate;
public DateTime EventDate
{
    get { return eventDate.LocalDateTime; }
    set { eventDate = new DateTimeOffset(value); }
}
```

Then you can use `eventDate` to serialize to JSON.

Or to set `Kind`:

```
picker.DataBindings.Add("Value", this, "EventDate");
...
private DateTime eventDate;
public DateTime EventDate
{
    get { return eventDate; }
    set
    {
        // Create a copy of DateTime and set Kind to Local since Kind is readonly
        eventDate = new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local);
    }
}
```

Both should work.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can go with solution, since `DateTimePicker` is not playing with `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: @Pablo What `DateTimePicker` are you using? Can you convert `DateTime` to a `DateTimeOffset` in the callback?

Comment: using regular Windows Forms `DateTimePicker` from 4.0 Dot Net framework. Not sure what callbacks you refer..

Comment: Moreover, I don't understand why `DateTime.Now` producing desired result, but with binding my DateTime object is not good enough for JSON.NET to specify TZ.

Comment: @Pablo How do you retrieve the picked `DateTime` value and when do you serialize it to JSON? I mean, can you convert it to `DateTimeOffset` before the serialization?

Comment: @Pablo And for you 2nd question regarding `DateTime.Now` and manually constructed `DateTime`, the difference is `DateTime.Now` has `Kind` equal to `DateTimeKind.Local` while the other is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. So this is an alternative way to put this information in JSON. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: OK that's good finding indeed about `Kind`. Now is there any way to tell DateTimePicker to give me local time? Alternatively, how should I alter DateTime given by DateTimePicker in order to convert it to local date/time?

Comment: @Pablo You can do that in the property getter/setter. I just updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Looks good to me, I'll double check now and accept your answer if nothing more comes out. Thx

Comment: ok removed my comment since you modified your answer and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

I use this.

It works very well.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
});
```