# Best way to transfer datetimes between client and server (c# / javascript)

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, serialization

I searched this on goolge and stackoverflow but couldn't find any satisfying answers.

I had some troubles with datetimes and timezones and i was wondering what the best way would be to transfer datetimes back and forth between server (c#) and client (javascript) **ignoring the timezone**.

I use JavaScriptSerializer on server and JSON.stringify on client.

Currently i convert the dates into ticks.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What problems have you been having? In the past I've converted dates to UTC and used that

Comment: UTC or Unix Time Stamp if you're not going lower than 1st Jan 1970

Comment: @jasonscript I have problems with the timezones, for example: if server sends datetime to client with different timezone the time of the object on client is different (+/- hours difference of timezone)

Comment: @RazvanDumitru could you provide an example? UTC gets lost on serialization in server -> client case.

Comment: Best way you need look at this?http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-date-time.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually time SHOULD be different because of timezone. Hours (and sometimes minutes if zone definition includes minutes) are changed as well as zone, when client deserializes datetime in a different timezone. If you want client to get same `hours` and `minutes` [clear zone info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) before serialization.

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Slatin, i realize now that my question was wrong. Actually it should be ***how do i transfer a datetime from c# to javascript respecting the timezone***. When the datetime gets deserialized in javascript the timezone is lost.

Comment: well in this case this should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/25105519/4573999. Looks like in your case you should do the opposite to what I supposed and set `kind` to `local`

Comment: however all these methods suppose you treat dateTime as dateTime not as ticks, which do not contain zone info...